# Where clause issue when parsing JSON file using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to parse a `JSON` file which has 6 million lines. Which something looks like this:

**temp.json**

```
{
  "bbc.com": {
    "Reputation": "2.1",
    "Rank": "448",
    "Category": [
      "News"
    ]
  },
  "amazon.com": {
    "Reputation": "2.1",
    "Rank": "448",
    "Category": [
      "Shopping"
    ]
  }
}
```

I know how to parse the "Keys" alone. To get "Keys" of this `JSON` structure, I
tried,

```
jq -r 'keys[]' temp.json
```

Result :

```
amazon.com
bbc.com
```

To get the "Category" in the above JSON file . I tried ,

```
jq -r '.[].Category[]' temp.json
```

Result :

```
Shopping
News
```

How to get the "Keys" where the "Category" only with "Shopping"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `to_entries` function as in:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.value.Category | index("Shopping") != null) | .key'
```

Answer (score 5):

In this particular case, `to_entries` and its overhead can be avoided while still yielding a concise and clear solution:

```
keys[] as $k | select( .[$k].Category | index("Shopping") != null) | $k
```

Comment: agreed, though both answers deserve to be listed